# Is there any way to update SQL Server job step command text using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2000, sql-agent-job

I have some jobs in my SQL Server 2000 Agent.

Now I need to update only step `command text`.

Is there any way to do this from code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this. There are several stored procedures in the `msdb` database of your server.

You need the permission `sysadmin` OR

- SQLAgentUserRole
- SQLAgentReaderRole
- SQLAgentOperatorRole

Check out:

- [MSDN - sp_update_jobstep (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189827.aspx)
- [MSDN - sp_add_jobstep (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187358.aspx)
- [MSDN - sp_delete_jobstep (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177582.aspx)
- [MSDN - sp_help_jobstep (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178599.aspx)